# Trying to display/printing latitude and longitude from Geolocation Field to node template

Tags: 8, theming

I've been trying to figure how I can fetch the latitude and longitude values using geolocation field and display it on my `node.html.twig` template.

I've been using to `kint()` to see how I would be able to fetch but I can't seem to figure out the right syntax. It seems to be inside an array

Tried `node.field_geolocation.latitude.value` or `node.field_geolocation.longitude.value`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `{{ node.field_geolocation['x-default']['lat'] }}` or `{{ content.field_geolocation['x-default']['lat'] }}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this by printing, `{{ node.field_geolocation.lat }}` and `{{ node.field_geolocation.lng }}`.

That should print the values.